# C# combobox dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms

I Want my combobox to drop down when i press the textfield and the dropdown symbol

I have done this:

```
private void comboBoxOpretKomponentLevel_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    if (comboBoxOpretKomponentLevel.SelectedIndex <= 0)
    {
        comboBoxOpretKomponentLevel.Text = null;
    }
    comboBoxOpretKomponentLevel.Focus();       
    comboBoxOpretKomponentLevel.DroppedDown = true;           
}
```

The .Droppeddown = true makes it work if text is selected ("Select Product")
But when the dropdown symbol of dropbox is pressed - the droppeddown goes false again.
How do I make this work?
And as far as I know I cant use DropDownList because i can´t have my ("Select Product") Text.

Comment: When I press it again it goes false? do you mean it closes...? because isnt that expected behavior

Comment: OK  maybe I haven´t explained it good enough!
When I press the drop down symbol - the drop down opens - but when it enters the _Enter Event it closes the drop down again when it executes the .Dropdown = true command.
So the result is that it quickly opens the dropdown list and then closes it again.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use the `MouseClick`event. Since you're question is too broad I only have this piece of code that may help you.

What it does is that only if you `click` the `ComboBox` or any controller regarding that `ComboBox` it is going to open the `dropdownlist`. To close it simply `click` on the `Form_Load` event and it will idle the `dropdownlist`

```
private void comboBoxOpretKomponentLevel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //This piece will dropdown the combobox once you click it.
        comboBoxOpretKomponentLevel.DroppedDown = true;
        comboBoxOpretKomponentLevel.Focus();  
    }
private void YourForm_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This piece will simply close the dropdown from your combobox and  use the selected value.
        comboBoxOpretKomponentLevel.DroppedDown = false;

    }
```

Hope it helps, otherwise simple reformulate your question so we can help you.